we are getting issue in edge browser when ag chart its automatically resize height to 1, canvas height changes automatically.Working fine in chrome
when using ag chart it works fine in chrome , but in edge canvas height is change to 1 automatically
need to know reason of dynamic change in canvas height in edge. want to know reason behind dynamic height change. Other way of changing canvas height.
